# Celery Best Practice For one Task Kicking off Many Small tasks

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, celerybeat

I have a novice level of experience with celery. I have written many tasks both scheduled and one off delayed jobs, but that is it.

I am running into an issue where I want to create one task that kicks off 1000s of smaller jobs to mitigate any issues that could arise with queue length and a job the could take hours to complete.

The current application relies on information from external APIs. So to speak a user links their account with another service I have integrated, and I want to update the user's information daily with changes on their external account.

I have a scheduled job like this

```
@app.task() 
def refresh_accounts():
    for account in Account.objects.all():
        response = retrieve_account_info(account_id=account.id)
        account.data = response.data 
        account.save()
```

--

What I desire is something like this

```
@app.task()
def kickoff_refresh():
    for account in Account.objects.all()
        refresh_account.delay(account_id=account.id)

@app.task() 
def refresh_account(account_id=None):
    account = Account.objects.get(id=account_id)
    response = retrieve_account_info(account_id=account.id)
    account.data = response.data 
    account.save()
```

one approach I was thinking of was having `kickoff_refresh` and `refresh_account` in different queues. `@app.task(queue=q1)`, `@app.task(queue=q2)`... I, however, do not know if there is a better way of doing this. Calling a task inside a task on the same queue seems to be bad practice in celery - https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#avoid-launching-synchronous-subtasks the task `kickoff_refresh` would be a periodic task running every several hours.

I would love to hear what works for others. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from celery import group


@app.task()
def kickoff_refresh(account_id=None):
    job = group(refresh_account.s(account_id=account.id) for account in Account.objects.all())()

@app.task()
def refresh_account(account_id=None):
    account = Account.objects.get(id=account_id)
    response = retrieve_account_info(account_id=account.id)
    account.data = response.data 
    account.save()
```

Comment: So I am having a lot of trouble unit testing this now. It seems to not call `refresh_account` even when I try running the function without a delay. Any ideas?

Comment: ehh I guess it's the signature, I gotta set up the test suite to always be eager

Comment: Check my edit, I forgot to add () at the end of the group line

Comment: I'm calling .delay in my job any difference?

Comment: Group takes a list of signatures

Comment: Yea I was calling delay on the group, I appreciate the help! Do you know if each signature opens a new connection to redis? I noticed this approach reached the connection limit on my redis server which is something I'll have to dig into. I bumped the plan for now

Comment: You can try setting the `redis_max_connections` setting for the redis backend and see if that limits Celery to one connection.

Comment: I did do that. I actually posted another questions about it if you have a moment to glance. I tried reverting to the old plan with the limit set and still got a bunch of issues. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61860262/celery-redis-connectionerrormax-number-of-clients-reached