# Celery Redis ConnectionError('max number of clients reached',)

Tags: python, django, redis, celery

I have a django application leveraging celery for asynchronous tasks. I've been running into an issue where I reach the max number of redis connections. I am fairly new to both celery and redis.

I'm confused because in my config I define - `CELERY_REDIS_MAX_CONNECTIONS = 20` which is the limit on my redis plan.

For experimentation, I bumped the plan up and that solved the issue. I am confused, however, that I am running into this problem again after defining the max number of connections. I downgraded the plan and set the limit to the plans max.

I am wondering if the `BROKER_POOL_LIMIT` needs to be changed.

Is there anything I am missing to help solve connection errors and celery.

Is it possible to figure out how many connections all of my tasks need? I have 16 jobs running every minute.

Another thought, I noticed that connecting the redis cli threw the connection error, is it possible that I am at the limit, and accessing the cli is putting me over?

I also cant kill connections because I cannot connect to the redis cli while it throws this error.

Comment: Apart from `broker_pool_limit` (all Celery configuration settings are now lower-case - maybe Djago integration still expects upper-case, idk) you can try to change your broker_transport_options. Something like: `broker_transport_options = {'fanout_prefix': True, 'fanout_patterns': True, 'max_connections': 10, 'socket_keepalive': True}`